# Ansible Using --extra-vars for conditional includes

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible to deploy an environment that may have services distributed or not.  I would like to conditionally include playbooks based on arguments I pass to ansible-playbook.

create_server.yml

```
---
- include: launch_ec2_instance.yml

- include install_postgres.yml
  when {{db}} == "Y"

- include install_redis.yml
  when {{redis}} == "Y"
```

Here is how I am calling create_server.yml

```
ansible-playbook create_server.yml -i local --extra-vars "db=Y redis=N"
```

Is it possible to do this and if so, how?

Answer (score 15):

Yes. It's possible. You are missing a colon(:) on your when statement.

```
---
- include: launch_ec2_instance.yml

- include install_postgres.yml
  when: {{ db }} == "Y"

- include install_redis.yml
  when: {{ redis }} == "Y"
```

You can also omit the braces ({{ }}):

```
---
- include: launch_ec2_instance.yml

- include install_postgres.yml
  when: db == "Y"

- include install_redis.yml
  when: redis == "Y"
```

Comment: Oddly enough it doesn't work for me... Even when I add the missing ":" after the include in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

@Rico's answer is correct except that it only applies when your include statement is part of a task.

Eg.

```
---
tasks:
  - include install_postgres.yml
    when: db == "Y"
```

If your playbook is just a bunch of includes as your 'create_server.yml' seems to be then 'when' wont work.

Comment: Seems to be [available since version 2.0](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-and-includes) `In versions prior to 2.0 this worked with task includes but not playbook includes. 2.0 allows it to work with both.`